# Multiplication Error oN vb

Tags: vb.net, vba, graph

I am doing project with VB.I have attached my code below.I can print current , voltage . Now i wanted to print wattage buy multiplying voltage and current factor. But problem is it not showing wattage properly . It showing me some other reading. Let me Know how to solve this ???
[image: Graph output]

And also For instantaneous watt-hour below it not showing time.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Static counter As Integer = 0
        Static average_sum As Double = 0
        Static Avg_count As Integer = 0

        Dim Power As Double
        Static Cc_count As Long = 0
        Static watt_hour As Double = 0
        Dim Counter_write As Integer = 60
        Try

            SerialPort1.Write("c")
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
            Dim k As Double
            Dim distance As String = SerialPort1.ReadLine()
            Dim voltage As Double = 24
            Dim PD As Double
            k = CDbl(distance)
            voltage_text.Text = 24
            ListBoxSensor.Text = k
            PD = k * voltage
            Display.Text = CStr(PD)

            Dim s As New Series
            counter = counter + 1
            'Count_val.Text = counter

            Avg_count = Avg_count + 1
            ' drawing graph 

            If Avg_count = 1 Then
                Power = (k * voltage) / 3600
                watt_hour = watt_hour + Power
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
                If watt_hour > 1000 Then
                    watt_hour = 1.0 + watt_hour
                End If

                Avg_count = Avg_count + 1

            End If
            If Avg_count > 1 Then
                Avg_count = 0
            End If

            Dim current As Double = watt_hour
            'Dim current As Double = k
            Dim r As DataRow = dT.NewRow
            r("time") = Now
            'r("current") = k
            r("current") = watt_hour
            'add the row
            dT.Rows.Add(r)

            'remove any row older than 1 minute
            Dim oldestTime As DateTime = Now.AddMinutes(-1)
            Do While DirectCast(dT.Rows(0)("time"), DateTime) < oldestTime

                dT.Rows.RemoveAt(0)

            Loop
            'finally bind the chart....
            Chart1.DataBind()

            'write into excel sheet for every 1 minute ..................
            If Cc_count < 1 Then
                Cc_count = Cc_count + 1
                Dim array(10) As Double
                For value As Double = 0 To Cc_count
                    array(Cc_count) = distance
                    average_sum = average_sum + array(Cc_count)
                    value = value + 1
                    'V_count.Text = value

                    ' AVG_count_text.Text = Cc_count
                    If value > 1 Then
                        average_sum = average_sum / value
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
                        ' AVG_CR1.Text = average_sum
                        Cc_count = 0
                    End If

                Next

            End If

            If counter = 1 Then
                counter = 0
                Dim headerText = ""
                'Dim headerText As New StringBuilder=
                Dim csvFile As String = IO.Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "Current.csv")
                If Not IO.File.Exists((csvFile)) Then
                    'headerText = "Date,TIME ,current, "
                    headerText = "Date,TIME ,Watt-Hour,Current, "
                End If

                Using outFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(csvFile, True)
                    If headerText.Length > 0 Then
                        outFile.WriteLine(headerText)
                    End If

                    'Dim date1 As String = TimeOfDay.Day + "-" + TimeOfDay.Month() + "-" + TimeOfDay.Year()
                    Dim date1 As String = "26-09-2014"
                    Dim time1 As String = TimeOfDay()
                    'Dim date1 As String = DateAndTime.DateString
                    ' Dim current1 As String = CStr(distance)
                    Dim watt1 As String = CStr(watt_hour) + " "
                    ' Dim current1 As String =CStr(distance)
                    Dim x As String = date1 + "," + time1 + "," + watt1 + "," + distance
                    ' Dim x As String = time1 + "," + distance + "," + watt1
                    outFile.Write(x)

                End Using
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

            ' MsgBox("Error in Timer1_Tick: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
```

And also plotting graph instantaneous .But Not doing as expected.

```
Dim current As Double = watt_hour
            'Dim current As Double = k
            Dim r As DataRow = dT.NewRow
            r("time") = Now
            'r("current") = k
            r("current") = watt_hour
            'add the row
            dT.Rows.Add(r)

            'remove any row older than 1 minute
            Dim oldestTime As DateTime = Now.AddMinutes(-1)
            Do While DirectCast(dT.Rows(0)("time"), DateTime) < oldestTime

                dT.Rows.RemoveAt(0)

            Loop
            'finally bind the chart....
            Chart1.DataBind()
```

Comment: What is the exact value of `distance` you read from the COM port?

Comment: The details are important: Please add a definite example including the string from the serial port, the value of voltage and the result you get by multiplying them. Since conversions from String to Double are involved, the exact number formats are important.

Comment: Put a breakpoint after `k = CDbl(distance)` and check what values the variables actually have. I can't reproduce your problem. Write a smaller, to the point example that reproduces the bahaviour if you can't find the problem in the values. The last bit basically goes for your other code as well.

Comment: anyone know How to enable running time on VB. as shown in image